# psql error when I try to run through terminal

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

When I run psql in terminal this error shown
`badar:~$ psql`

`psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Answer (score 1):

I can see two possible issues:

1. Postgresql is not running

Find out:

```
ps aux | grep [p]ostgresql
```

Fix:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

---

2. Unix socket connections (local) have no permission.

Look for the following line in your pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

If you don't have it, add it! If it has an # in front, remove that. Then restart postgresql:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Reference: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75214/psql-could-not-connect-to-server-no-such-file-or-directory.
Hope this helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Best to mention the hostname and port (and if necessary user and password of database) where the database is located:

```
> psql -h <host> -p <port> -u <database>
> psql -h <host> -p <port> -U <username> -W <password> <database>
```